# How to create maven wab (war as osgi bundle) project in netbeans 7.4?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am sorry if my question is so simple, but I can't find it in netbeans. Does such project exist? If no, how do you create it?

As I understand there are two ways - 1)create maven osgi project and then edit it or 2)create maven war project and then edit it. Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is what you really looking for, but you can package *osgi* bundles with **maven-bundle-plugin**. Downside is a sample for a basic project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"...>
  <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Sample</name>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.groupId}.${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
              <Bundle-Name>${pom.name}</Bundle-Name>
              <Bundle-Version>${pom.version}</Bundle-Version>
              <Bundle-Activator>package.name.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
              <Private-Package>package.name.sample</Private-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration          
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here you can refer to the [documentation](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html).